# Default date is being set to current date in Material UI's Textfield with type="date"

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, material-ui

I am using Material UI's textfield with type set to "date" and seeing this issue where the date is being set to the current date instead of mm/dd/yyyy. Is there any way I can prevent that behavior and just show the mm/dd/yyyy instead when the user loads the page? I am setting the value with the value attribute to whatever the date is being returned from the database is so if there is a date coming from the db, it should show that, otherwise leave it as mm/dd/yyyy. Here is my code:

```
         <TextField
            className={classes.formInput}
            type="date"
            value={moment(dateOfPurchase).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}
            onChange={e => actions.setDateOfPurchase(e.target.value)}
            required
            variant="standard" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a state for the form.

`const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState ({ date: 'dd/mm/yyy' })`

On page load (useEffect) query the db, and if needed change the state

`setFormValues({ ...formValues, date: _dateInDb })`

And the value of the TextField will be = `formValues.date`